# How to work with checkboxes in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I have a view inside which there are two checkboxes. On checked I need to save currently assigned value into database table.

Here is the model:

```
public class RoomHk
{
  public int RoomHkId { get; set; }
  public int RoomId { get; set; }
  public DateTime? DeepCleaning { get; set; }
  public DateTime? NewLinen { get; set; }
}
```

This is the child table of my **Room** Table. Following is my view, suppose user check on first checkbox then he clicks on save button, then I want to save current datetime in the `NewLinen` column of the `RoomHk` table to that respective `RoomId`. How can I do it with jQuery post method?

```html
<div class="col-6">
  @if (item.NewLinen == null)
  {
    <input type="checkbox" data-nlid="@item.RoomId" class="form-check-input newLinen" />
    <label>New Linen</label>
    <br />
  }

  @if (item.DeepCleaning == null)
  {
    <input type="checkbox" data-dcid="@item.RoomId" class="form-check-input deepClean" />
    <label>Deep Cleaning</label>
  }
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default insert" data-rid="@item.RoomId">Save</button>
```

```js
$(function () {
  $('.insert').click(function () {
    $.post("@Url.Action("SetCleaningStatus", "HouseKeeping")", { id: $(this).data("id"), });
  });
});
```

Comment: Are you want to use AJAX instead of normal form submit with `BeginForm` helper? If you want to use AJAX, then you need to show parameters which applied in `SetCleaningStatus`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Html.BeginForm`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) and place the submit button **inside the form**. This is important, otherwise you'll need to employ additional scripts to get it working.

If you need to post the state of the two checkboxes (`DeepCleaning` and `NewLinen`) I'd suggest having them as `Boolean` instead of `DateTime` so you can have their states (checked/unchecked) mapped to the respective properties, because you seem to want to do that.

#### SetCleaningStatus.cshtml

```html
@model RoomHk;

@Html.BeginForm("SetCleaningStatus", "HouseKeeping") 
{
  <!-- Will be posted to the controller, no additional Javascript necessary -->
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.RoomId)

  <div class="col-6">
    @if (item.NewLinen == null)
    {
        <input type="checkbox" data-nlid="@item.RoomId" class="form-check-input newLinen" />
        <label>New Linen</label>
        <br />
    }

    @if (item.DeepCleaning == null)
    {
        <input type="checkbox" data-dcid="@item.RoomId" class="form-check-input deepClean" />
        <label>Deep Cleaning</label>
    }
  </div>


  <!-- IMPORTANT: the type needs to be `submit` instead of `button` -->
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default insert" value="Save" />
}
```

#### HouseKeeping.cs

```cs
public class RoomHk
{
    public int RoomHkId { get; set; }
    public int RoomId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DeepCleaning { get; set; }
    public DateTime? NewLinen { get; set; }
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SetCleaningStatus() 
{
    var model = new RoomHk();

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SetCleaningStatus(RoomHk arg) 
{
    bool response = new {
        success = true
    };

    // Here is your RoomId
    arg.RoomId;

    arg.NewLinen = DateTime.Now;

    // Save posted data to DB
    // ...

    // Return your response here
    return Json(response);
}
```

#### `POST`ting the checked state of checkboxes

Use [`Html.CheckBoxFor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.checkboxfor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) and [`Html.LabelFor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.labelextensions.labelfor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) and let the compiler render those fields for you, with the right IDs and names properly set.

```
public class RoomHk
{
    // Make them booleans
    public bool DeepCleaning { get; set; }
    public bool NewLinen { get; set; }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-6">
  <!--
  <input type="checkbox" data-nlid="@item.RoomId" class="form-check-input newLinen" />
  <label>New Linen</label>
  <br />
  -->

  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NewLinen, "New Linen")
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.NewLinen, new { @class = "form-check-input" })
</div>
```